# Typescript - How the class instance is created here please?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have some code here. My problem is that I don't manage to understand the way the instance is created. Why we use " : Calculator" ( line 3 ) to use after  " new Calculator" (line 4). There is a difference ? I know that I have a problem concerning Typescript but I found this code piece while I was looking for testing in Angular. Also I searched into some tutorials but I don't find explanation.

```
import { Calculator } from './calculator';
​
describe('Calculator', () => {

    let calculator: Calculator;

    beforeEach(() => {
        calculator = new Calculator();
    });
​
});
```

Comment: Read http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html#type-annotations

Comment: Typescript is a strongly-typed language.  `let calculator: Calculator` is specifying that the variable `calculator` is of the `Calculator` type.

Comment: It's unclear what your question is: `let calculator: Calculator` declares a variable of type `Calculator` once, but doesn't assign it. `calculator = new Calculator();` is called before every test, assigning a new `Calculator` for each test. Because of how jasmine, works, you often do `calculator = null` in an `afterEach`  to avoid memory problems;

Comment: [TypeScript new Operator](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#4.14)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, you use the : Calculator to **give a type** to that variable, on the other hand it is declared **outside beforeEach's scope** so it can be accesible on the tests.

If you did

```
beforeEach(() => {
    let calculator = new Calculator();
});
```

calculator won't be accessible.

Comment: @N.T let is recommended you can use var, let is used to 'scope' the variable. Creating the instance inside beforeEach will make the calculator variable unusable.

Answer (score 1):

Your "calculator.ts" file probably has something like:

```
export class Calculator {
    ...
}
```

When you do `import { Calculator } from './calculator';`, you import the Calculator class in your current file.

`let calculator: Calculator;` will declare a variable `calculator` giving it a type `Calculator` <- So you specifically say that you will have `Calculator` objects in this variable. This is for Typescripts understanding and code completion,

This will create a new instance of the class.

```
 calculator = new Calculator();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import { Calculator } from './calculator'; // importing Calculator class
​
describe('Calculator', () => { // Describing feature in BDD manner

    let calculator: Calculator; 
    // Declaring variable calculator so it's accessible within whole describe() block

    beforeEach(() => { // This hook will be called before each test in your feature
        calculator = new Calculator(); 
        // and therefore will create new instance of a Calculator for each test
    });

    // Here you probably will see something like

    it('should return sum of 2 numbers', () => {
        const result = calculator.add(2,3); // actual instance used
        expect(result).toEqual(5);
    });
​
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The line 3, means the type declaration of your variable, but at first is undefined, so you need to create a new instance of your type, that's why in the next line it does `new Calculator()`.